# Adding Event Handlers/Props to inner markup in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a Repeatable component in React. The goal is that it can be given any `group` that is a valid React component and take any list of `callbacks` and apply those callbacks to the `group` element. Below is what I have that kinda works and I will explain how it is different than what I am wanting to do after. Link to codepen:

http://codepen.io/cirsca/pen/vKqzjZ?editors=0011

My wrapping component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            callbacks: {
                onClick: (e) => console.log('I was clicked!')
            }
        }
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            <Repeatable 
                group={<Group />}
                {...this.state.callbacks}
            />
        </div>
    }
}
```

My Repeater Component:

```
class Repeatable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        const {group, ...callbacks} = this.props
        this.state = {
            group: group || <div>This is awesome!</div>,
            list: [group],
            callbacks
        }
    }

    addGroup = () => this.setState({
        list: [
            ...this.state.list,
            this.state.group
        ]
    });

    render(){
        return <div id={this.props.cssID || 'react_repeatable'}>
            <button onClick={this.addGroup}>Add Group</button>
            <div className="repeated__list">
                {this.state.list.map(el => {
                    return React.cloneElement(el, {...this.state.callbacks})
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

And my dummy Group component is:

```
const Group = ({className, ...callbacks}) => (
    <div className={className || 'repetable__block'} {...callbacks}>
        <p>Here is a repeatable group!</p>
    </div>
)
```

This works as long as I want to attach my callbacks to the root element in the `Group` component. What I am wanting is a way that my `callbacks` can be targeted towards the nested `p` tag or that I can not have a billion checks of `onClick={callbacks.onClick ? ....}` per each underlying component and action ( in case a new onAction comes out that I did not put into my code ).

I feel like I'm overly complicating things here but am unsure of where to look to find that out or what to google to get started. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursive clone children and pass props down

```
const recursiveCloneChildren = (children, props) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    let childProps = {};
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      childProps = props;
    }
    childProps.children = this.recursiveCloneChildren(child.props.children);
    return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
  })
}

const Group = ({className, children, ...callbacks}) => (
  <div className={className || 'repetable__block'} {...callbacks}>
    {recursiveCloneChildren(children, callbacks)}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to conceptualize and just couldn't break it down to smaller steps in my head. Thank you so much!